# Using ClickOnce for multiple deployment configurations

Tags: deployment, clickonce, build

I have a ClickOnce deployment that has different web service endpoints and strings that need to be changed in Settings.Settings. Right now I am only having to deal with on localized development version being done in house and one version that i push out to the customer for their UAT. Now i need 4 versions of this application. in house dev and testing, customer testing and production. I also need these 4 deployments to be able to be installed along side each other. I have discovered that i can change the name (i.e. APP -- INTERNAL -- TEST, APP -- INTERNAL -- DEV, APP -- CUST -- TEST, APP -- CUST -- PROD) and that will allow them all to be installed alongside each other. But, having to remember every place a string needs changed in the various settings.setting of each build, swapping the end points, changing the application names, changing the certificate, changing the deploy addreess and the url for each different build is time consuming and cumbersome. Is there a way to just say "Publish internal test build" and have it do the right thing? I was going to just write various mage scripts but I dont thing that gets me around having to mess with the settings.settings stuff. i didnt write this application nor maintain it but I suppose i could go in and use some sort of conditional logic, but the connections strings for instance are wired to reports and table adapter etc...  P.S. I hate ClickOnce

Comment: You should split your answer into logical paragraphs to make it easier to read... At the moment it looks like a wall of text and is hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for a useful answer and not a critique of my writing style. mage.exe is severly lacking in options on what it can an cannot do, it is also poorly documented and does not work as advertised. In order to accomplish what I wanted, I had to download sed for windows and write .bat files to manually rename files to .deploy. I used sed to edit the manifest files and flip options on and off and keep track of the different deployments. So in short write a batch file using mage.exe and sed and have a very good understanding of the contents of a manifest file. Feel free to contact me and I can send scripts that will automate multiple ClickOnce deployments, add the .deploy extension, require a specific version number before start up etc... none of these are possible using the tools MSFT provides.